How to unwrap polygons at the same scale in blender 4.0?
When I selected individual polygons from the model and click uv unwrap, the pieces would appear at different scales. Only polygons unwrapped together in the same unwrap would keep the same scale. Is there a setting in blender to keep it at the same scale?
This is for Blender 4.0


This looks like a question for the Blender StackExchange, no?
